# Which type of embedding is in keras Embedding layer, like word2vec or GloVe, or some other

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

How can i change the type of word embedding in keras.layers.Embedding to word2vec or someother

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a *frozen* Embedding layer with pre-trained word vectors:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            trainable=False)
```

where `embedding_matrix` is a regular NumPy matrix of shape `(num_words, EMBEDDING_DIM)`. So you have to load in word2vec etc into a numpy array with correct indices and set it as the initial values of your embedding layer. For a concrete examples have a look at [Keras example](https://keras.io/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings/).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of keras.layers.Embedding is simply a matrix that map word index to a vector, AND it is 'untrained' when you initialize it.

You can either train your word embedding so that the Embedding matrix will map your word index to a word vector based on your training.

Or, you can initialize the Embedding layer and then load pre-trained weight from word2vec or GloVe.

From keras example https://keras.io/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings/, you can see that it loads pre-trained GloVe embeddings weight (the Matrix) and then load it into the Embedding layer. `embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix)` where `embedding_matrix` is the data from the loaded GloVe and have set `trainable=False`

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

If you dont' initalize your Embedding layer, it is just randomized weight. You cannot use it as you expected, or you have to train it yourself.